# How to change Default Python for Salt in CentOS 7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, salt-stack, salt-cloud

I am trying to setup a salt-master/salt-cloud on Centos 7. The issue that I am having is that I need Python 2.7.13 to use salt-cloud to clone vm in vmware vcenter (uses pyvmomi). CentOS comes with Python 2.7.5 which salt has a known issue with (SSL doesn't work).
I have tried to find a configuration file on the machine to change which python version it should use with no luck.

I see two possible fixes here,

somehow overwrite the python 2.7.5 with 2.7.13 so that it is the only python available.

OR 
If possible change the python path salt uses.

Any Ideas on how to do either of these would be appreciated? 
(Or another solution that I haven't mentioned above?)

Comment: http://tecadmin.net/install-python-2-7-on-centos-rhel/# ?

Comment: I have tried this but but salt is defaulting to the 2.7.5 that is installed and I haven't found a way to get it to use the "python2.7" (2.7.13) instead of python (2.7.5)

Comment: how did you install salt on the master?

Comment: https://repo.saltstack.com/#rhel I followed the step here. Is there a way to specify the python version at install?

Answer (score 1):

The salt packages are built using the system python and system site-packages directory.  If something doesn't work right, file a bug with salt.  You should avoid overwriting the stock python, as that will result in a broken system in many ways.